# Scipy Shift function losing precision

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

```
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift
a = np.array([0., 1.])
shift_left = shift(a, -1, cval=np.NaN)
shift_right = shift(a, 1, cval=np.NaN)
print(shift_left)
print(shift_right)
```

Here are the results from the code above

```
[ 1. nan]
[ nan -8.32667268e-17]
```

Here is what I would expect the results to be

```
[ 1. nan]
[ nan 0.]
```

Is there a reason for this loss of precision? Does anyone know what could be causing this issue and how I could fix it? Seems to happen when I shift arrays that contain the value 0, although this could be happening with other cases for all I know.

Comment: `1e-17` is basically zero. I do not know about the underlying algorithm(s), but getting tiny values like that is not uncommon. You should define an "epsilon" for your problem which can be treated as zero, or just ignore this tiny value, since it will likely not affect your further processing. [See this Matlab answer for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795087/getting-very-small-number-instead-of-zero).

Comment: If you want the definitive answer for your case you will have to look up the source code for the `scipy` interpolation function.

Comment: yeah, I understand it's basically zero, but I am using numpy argmin to pick the index with the minimum value, and I want to break ties by picking the smaller index. That doesn't work when values are not precise. I managed to fix it by just implementing my own shift function, but I would still like to know what is going on with scipy's shift.

Comment: You could set them to zero after calling the shift function by `shift_left[np.abs(shift_left) < np.finfo(np.float64).eps] = 0`.

Comment: What you see is not a loss in precision, but a result of floating point arithmetic. Your results are still smaller than the [machine epsilon for the float64 type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon). Results like that are expected when working with floating point numbers numerically.

Answer (score 1):

The number `-8.32667268e-17` you get is smaller than the (negative) [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) of the float64 type. Results like that are expected from algorithms handling floating point numbers. You can set all values smaller than the machine epsilon to zero after the shift:

```
def eps2zero(x, dtype=np.float64):
    """ this sets values < eps to zero in-place """
    x[np.abs(x) < np.finfo(dtype).eps] = 0
```